# Chaging Border Background Color on Texblock Value?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am trying to change the border background color to red if the child texblock gets value "0". I am trying to use GreaterThanZero Converter, but it fails to do anything. I am wondering if someone can help. I also need to change the texblock foreground color to white if value is greater than zero. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid>
<Border x:Name="TextBoxBorder" BorderThickness="1" Width="30">
   <TextBlock x:Name="TotalTileValue" Text="{Binding TotalItemCount}">
    <TextBlock.Style>      
        <Style>        
            <Style.Triggers>          
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content, Converter={x:Static local:GreaterThanZeroConverter.Instance}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" >            
                      <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />  
                      <Setter TargetName="TextBoxBorder" Property="Background" Value="#FFCC0000" />     
                </DataTrigger>        
            </Style.Triggers>      
        </Style>    
    </TextBlock.Style>             
   </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to process the text of the TextBox? Try to bind to the `Text`-Property instead of the content-Property.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, Converter={x:Static local:GreaterThanZeroConverter.Instance}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" >
```

However maybe this is only the half story. It depends on the converter. If it processes string-values, it will do.

**Edit**
As desired, here a start on how to build you own value converter. Please note, I don't know about your exact requirement. Also I have not tested the code. It should only be a start-point for your own converter:

```
public class GreaterThanZeroValueConverter : IValueConverter{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        if (null == value) {
            return false;
        }
        int intValue = 0;
        if (value is string) {                
            if (!Int32.TryParse((string)value,out intValue)) {
                return false;
            }                
        }
        if (value is int) {
            intValue = (int)value;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Type ["+value.GetType().Name+"]");
        }
        return intValue > 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I cannot do that. This way the specified 'Text' cast is not valid. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @vladc77: This is what I meant by my last line. Binding to Content is useless, because you have no Content-Property on the TextBlock. Therefore nothing happens. However if you bind to Text, the binding works, but because your converter does not know how to convert string to int, it throws an exception. You have to extend the converter for string-values. Something like: if(value is string){int intValue=0;Int32.TryParse((string)value,out intValue);return intValue>0;}...

Comment: I don't have access to the converter. It is packed in dll. It looks like I will need to create new one. I am wondering if you have any good sample. Thank you again.

Comment: @vladc77: I have updated my answer. I have not tested it, but I assume that it will do. I hope this is worth a little upvote :)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will work on it. It looks like what I need. I still have problem applying converter to Text property with this converter. I hope I will find what is the issue.